# TextView shows in AndroidStudio but not on device nor DebugMonitor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a popup which is shown when I receive a GCM notification. The popup is implemented as a LinearLayout which is setContentView'd in the popup activity. The layout render in Android Studio looks like this:

[image: screenshot of Android Studio]

However, on the device and on the DebugMonitor View Hierarchy dump it does not show, although it is there:

[image: screenshot of DebugMonitor's View Hierarchy dump]

The TextView has the default text "Where?" replaced in the extended Activity class:

```
    String lightName = getIntent().getStringExtra(LIGHT_NAME_KEY);
    final TextView lightNameLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lightNameLabel);
    lightNameLabel.setText(lightName);
```

I am at a loss here. I grep'ed through the project files and there are no other uses of the TextView's id other than in the snippet above. Could you please give me some pointers where to investigate why the TextView doesn't show?

[edit] I am including the .xml snippet for the respective TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/lightNameLabel"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:text="Where?"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

[edit 2] A link to the whole layout .xml file: http://pastebin.com/2uqkzBSa

Comment: check your String lightName its coming as "".

Comment: sadly, this does not happen, and this was the first thing I checked. I must add that I used the same layout before setting the string (so it should only display "Where?") but it was still missing

Comment: Are you sure you've haven't got font colour set to white? Just want to eradicate silly issues first.

Comment: that is the 2nd thing I checked :) I am going to edit the question shortly so that I include the .xml snippet for the textview

Comment: Okay nice, that would help.

Comment: Have you debugged and checked whether the `Intent` is actually returning a String value and not null?

Comment: yes, I have a Log.d which displays the string "Kitchen" in the extras; then I stepped through the 2 lines of code which set the text of the TextView, and there is a member mText (or so) set to "Kitchen"; you can see that in the DebugMonitor the TextView is wide enough to have something non-null in there; also, the DebugMonitor says that the selected TextView should have the text to "Kitchen"

Comment: can you please put whole layout code ?

Comment: sure, I am linking it to pastebin, to keep clutter down

Comment: I'm thinking that it could possibly be that you have a weightSum on the `LinearLayout` but haven't declared any weights for the children. Try removing that.

Comment: I must have missed that, you are right, it should be removed. However, it turns out that the default theme of the app has a light text color on light background (see below, the answer). Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was helpful that you showed a screenshot, as the problem is likely that you're displaying the layout in a dialog. If you select the Holo dialog theme in Android Studio's graphical editor pane, you'll observe that the default text color is white. Since you've provided a light background, the light text is simply illegible against it.

There are different solutions:

- Provide a different theme when displaying the dialog as to ensure that the primary colors are dark; or
- Define your own theme and provide it when displaying the dialog; or
- Modify the layout to specify a text color.

Comment: oh my, this is exactly what happened. Thank you very much! For the record, my solution was to set the text color of the TextView to `@android:color/secondary_text_light`.

Comment: Haha @csima. I thought it was the colour. Glad you've got it sorted now. :P